# Laravel 5.1 Ajax to get html from Blade View

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a myitems($filter) method in a ItemsController that loads the myitems.blade view.

The view has list of items as label and text box to get number of items  ($items is passed from myitems method to myitems view and there is a model form binding on items model as well)

I have a select box that has options 1. All, 2. Expired and 3.New

When I change the selection I want to have get new $items from the controller and recreate the form with new items list.

I am using using jquery to alert that the selection is changed. but I am not able to figure out how will I be able to call myitems($filter) from ajax and redirect to create the items.blade page.

Comment: you don't want to redirect if using ajax right? you want to modify the existing dom with the new data? `$('#myitems').on('change',function(){ var myItems = $(this).val(); /* call ajax with your route that hits your controller which returns the data to the dom */ }).success(function(data){ /* populate your list box with $.each perhaps */ });`  without having any code to see route / controller / view its pretty hard to give a specific example but those are the steps to get you where you need to be I hope they help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in in right direction, I was able to achieve it based on your direction and [laravel.io thread](http://laravel.io/forum/09-23-2014-loading-views-with-ajax). It turned out to be simpler than i imagined it to be.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Route**

```
//Note the ? in parameter, it says parameter is optional
Route::get('/myitems/{filter?}', 
    ['as' => 'myitems.list', 'uses' => 'ItemController@myitems']
);
```

**Controller**

```
...
public function myitems(Request $request, $filter = null)
{
    if (empty($filter)) $filter=1;

    $items = Item::where('item_type', $filter)->get();

    // if ajax call just return the partial that displays the list
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return view('_itemlist', compact('items'));
    }

    // passed as options to input select
    $filters= [
           'All' => '0',
           'New' => '1',
           'Expired' => '2'
    ];
    return view('itempagewith_defaultitemlist', compact('items','filters'));
}
...
```

**View**

view *itempagewith_defaultitemlist.blade.php*

```
<div class="container">
{!! Form::model($myitems, ['route' => 'myitems.list', 'class'=>'form-horizontal', 'files' => true]) !!}

<div id="filterselectbox">
    <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::label('filterselectbox','*Filter:',['class'=>'control-label']) !!}            
            {!!Form::select('filterselectbox', $filters, null, ['class'=>'form-control ']) !!}
     </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

<div id="item-container">
    @include('_itemlist')
</div>

<script>
$('#filterselectbox').change(function() {
    var id = $('#filterselectbox').val();
    var ajaxurl = '{{route('myitems', ':id')}}';
    ajaxurl = ajaxurl.replace(':id', id);
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data){
            $data = $(data); // the HTML content that controller has produced
            $('#item-container').hide().html($data).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
</script>                   

</div>
```

partial view *_itemlist.blade.php*

```
 <ul>
     @foreach ($items as $item)
    <li>{{ $item->name }}</li>
     @endforeach
 </ul>
```

Comment: This is the best self-answerd question that I have seen so far. But I dont understand why you put the script and the wrapping div with `id=item-container` in `_itemlist.blade.php`. I think you should put the code from `<ul>` to `</ul>` in `_itemlist.blade.php`  the otherstuff doesnot belong there. Otherwise your HTML code looks like this : `<div id="item-container"><div id="item-container"><div id="item-container"><div id="item-container">....`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I will test it and update it soon. This is from the era I was just starting to learn Laravel, couple of years old. Thanks Again